# How to solve Deprecated Main class in Cucumber?

Tags: testing, automation, cucumber, bdd, feature-file

I am getting the following error:

> Nov 20, 2023 8:45:24 PM cucumber.api.cli.Main run WARNING: You are
> using deprecated Main class. Please use io.cucumber.core.cli.Main
>
> Scenario: Verifying login function by giving username and password #
> src/test/resource/Feature/Login.feature:3
>
> Scenario: Moving to product tags after logging #
> src/test/resource/Feature/Login.feature:11
>
> 0 Scenarios 0 Steps 0m0.443s
>
> ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
> │ Share your Cucumber Report with your team at
> https://reports.cucumber.io          │ │ Activate publishing with one
> of the following:                                    │ │
> │ │ src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:
> cucumber.publish.enabled=true    │ │
> src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties:
> cucumber.publish.enabled=true    │ │ Environment variable:
> CUCUMBER_PUBLISH_ENABLED=true    │ │ JUnit:
> @CucumberOptions(publish = true) │ │
> │ │ More information at https://reports.cucumber.io/docs/cucumber-jvm
> │ │
> │ │ Disable this message with one of the following:
> │ │
> │ │ src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:
> cucumber.publish.quiet=true      │ │
> src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties:
> cucumber.publish.quiet=true      │
> └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

I just created a feature file and expect the step definition steps to be generated.

I have also added required dependencies:

- cucumber-java
- cucumber-junit (version is 6.9.0)

How do I resolve this issue?